# Track the time that Aurelia need to create/refresh the view, after data update

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way in Aurelia, to track the time from receiving the data from the ajax request till completing/refreshing the view with that data. I would like to log the time for generating/regenerating the templates, after receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gulp, gulp reports how much time each task takes.

[image]

If you're using Chrome DevTools, the network tab will report how long each request takes, as well as how long the entire page took.

[image]

Comment: I'm not looking for that. What I want is to have FE performance log, not related with the server side. I only need to track the time for JS rendering.